# Newline gets prepended when sending form with Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara

I have this test in a Rails app, using Capybara:

```
within "#register" do
  fill_in "Biography (optionnal)", :with => "Hello world!"
end

click_on "Save"

# Check that form is repopulated with old input
expect(find_field('user_bio').value).to eq('Hello world!')
```

Here's what I get from the test:

```
Failure/Error: expect(find_field('user_bio').value).to eq('Hello world!')   
expected: "Hello world!"
got: "\nHello world!"
```

At no time do I prepend a newline to the user_bio field manually.

**Where could this come from?**

**Edit 1:**
after some Googling, there seems to have been a PR on Github for that, and it got merged. So I guess it's not a bug from Capybara. See https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/commit/755a724d4b10e6841a0eeb58af43375236b33247

Comment: Please add a reproduction case so we'll be able to reproduce it. You can start from [this](https://gist.github.com/jnicklas/5137053)

Comment: What does clicking Save do? Does that submit the form? Make an AJAX request?

Comment: It looks like there's another bug in Capybara: https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/1068

Comment: Does it pass if you do the assertion on the Model instead of through Capybara?

Answer (score 0):

you can do a before save filter to clear that new line

in your model add

```
 before_save :clear_new_lines

 protected
 def clear_new_lines
   self.user_bio = user_bio.gsub("\n",'')
 end
```